# How to copy lines with line numbers?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, line-numbers

I would like to copy several lines with line numbers; the text from `set number` isn't copied. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: When Vim runs within ``tmux`` (and possibly other tools), you could achieve this by using the copy mode; assuming you have the ``set numbers`` on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several alternatives.

1. **Use the `TOhtml` command** to let Vim generate an HTML file, which includes the line numbers, and then copy and paste from that file.
2. **Replace each line by its line number plus its content**, so you can copy it with the line number. This can be done by visually selecting the lines, and using the following substitute command:

   ```
   :s/^/\=printf("%2d ", line('.'))/
   ```

   You obviously want to undo this replace after copying using e.g. undo 
   or `:s/^\d\+ //`
3. **Create your own command** to take care of copying the desired 
   text together with the line numbers. Something like this should work:

   ```
   fu! s:yank_number(first, last) 
       let start = a:first 
       let l = [] 
       while start <= a:last 
           let l = add(l, printf("%" . len(a:last) . "d %s", start, " " . getline(start))) 
           let start += 1
       endwhile 
       return join(l, "\n") . "\n" 
   endfu 

   command! -nargs=0 -range Yank :let @+ = s:yank_number(<line1>, <line2>)
   ```

   Now select your text and enter `:Yank`, which will copy the range to the `+`-register (which should correspond to your system's clipboard, if your Vim was compiled with clipboard functionality (`:help` should output `+clipboard`, instead of `-clipboard`).
4. **Use `:redir`**:

   ```
   :redir @a 
   :silent! :'<,'>number
   :redir END
   ```

   or

   ```
   :redir @a | silent! :'<,'>number | redir END
   ```

   to pull the numbered lines into register "a".  This can be 
   wrapped into a mapping:

   ```
   :vnoremap <f4> :<home>redir @a<bar>silent! <end>number<bar>redir END<cr>
   ```

   assuming you always want to trump the same register.  If you use 
   it frequently, you might designate a preferred register such as 
   "n" for "(n)umbered" and then only use it for that purpose. 
   Alternatively, `:redir` allows you to redirect to other sinks if 
   you prefer.

---

DISCLAIMER: The above options have been created from the [Vim mailing list thread](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/set-nu-gt-how-to-copy-lines-with-line-numbers-td1186325.html), using:

- [Krzysztof Cierpisz's question](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/set-nu-how-to-copy-lines-with-line-numbers-tp1186325.html)
- [Christian Brabandt's answer](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/set-nu-how-to-copy-lines-with-line-numbers-tp1186325p1186331.html)
- [Tim Chase's answer](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/set-nu-how-to-copy-lines-with-line-numbers-tp1186325p1186326.html)
- [Bee-16's answer](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/set-nu-how-to-copy-lines-with-line-numbers-tp1186325p5597007.html)

If you are one of the above authors, and would like to take credit for it, please let me know, and I will delete the question and answer so that you can re-create it.

Comment: You can use `execute()` instead of `:redir` to not clobber a register: `:echo execute("'<,'>#")`. I've also found some weird bugs with `:redir` over the years, and generally try to avoid it.

Comment: `execute()` did not exists back when that question was initially asked

Comment: Hi @MartinTournoij ..  I use `redir` to load the clipboard with a command's output pretty often. I don't recall ever having problems. OTOH I've only been doing this for, oh, the last 3 years or so so perhaps there were issues but they've since been fixed. Have you had any problems that you recall in that same rough time frame? (Out of curiosity primarily. Thanks.)

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the text with the mouse if you do *not* have the mouse enabled (e.g. `set mouse=`), and enable `number`.

This will work in any terminal, and also seems to work in the GTK3 version of gvim (but may not work in all gvim versions).

From the perspective of the terminal there is no difference between the number column on the left and the buffer contents; it's all just text. This can be either a good or bad thing, depending on what you want. If you want to copy the number column then it's a good thing :-)

Comment: with mouse enabled, I think one can use `shift` + mouse click to copy. However, this might be problematic, if you have vertical split windows open.

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated? The easy way to to this is with the `grep` and `tee` commands.

> **Disclaimer**: before you start messing with files with the `tee` command make an alias in your `.profile` for the command:
>
> `alias tee="tee -a"`
>
> The `-a` flag tells `tee` to append to rather than obliterate the
> file. What `tee` does specifically is take `stdout` and redirects it
> to files, similar to
>
> `echo some text > file.`
>
> But it works with what is produced on the terminal.

In order to use `tee` properly we need to get some `stdout` and that is where `grep` comes in.

What you want to do is `grep` (find) the text you want to produce which by default will put the text as `stdout`. You can also add lines before or after the line you want with `-A`, `-B`, and `-C` flags. Also, to add line number you can add the `-n` flag. So if you add `-A5` for example, you will get the line you grep for plus 5 lines after that. Similarly with `-B5` but in this case you get the line you grep for plus 5 lines before what you grep for. `-C5` you get 5 lines before and after meaning 10 lines plus what you grep for. The `-n` flag gets you your line numbers.

The command:

```
grep -n[-ABC][num] "search line" | tee [-a, unless you alias it already] [file]
```

This command is a lot more simple. You see everything on the screen.
The only drawback (if it is a drawback) is that when `grep` adds line numbers, it does so with a colon and each line after that gets a dash like this:

```
33: text....
34- text....
35- text....
```

However seeing how you are injecting line numbers to begin with, this is a good visual clue, especially if you have line numbers enabled in your text editor.

It could get real confusing otherwise.

Enjoy.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Interesting answer to the question, but it doesn't really address how this integrates with vim.

Comment: Actually integration is more of a Vim thing which isn't as consistent with the unix way of doing one thing and do it well. Straight up vi is and should be a text editor, thats all it should be resigned to. Grep and tee commands are better suited for those results. Why make life hard.

Comment: Not here to argue about the philosophy—vim makes it easy to pull in these tools. My point is this a vi/vim site, so your answer should probably fit into that context.